# C - sscanf not working

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to extract a string and an integer out of a string using `sscanf`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char Command[20] = "command:3";
    char Keyword[20];
    int Context;

    sscanf(Command, "%s:%d", Keyword, &Context);

    printf("Keyword:%s\n",Keyword);
    printf("Context:%d",Context);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives me the output:

```
Keyword:command:3
Context:1971293397
```

I'm expecting this ouput:

```
Keyword:command
Context:3
```

Why does `sscanf` behaves like this? Thanks in advance you for your help!

Comment: Is there a good reason you don't check the result of `sscanf`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`sscanf` expects the `%s` tokens to be whitespace delimited (tab, space, newline), so you'd have to have a space between the string and the :

for an ugly looking hack you can try:

```
sscanf(Command, "%[^:]:%d", Keyword, &Context);
```

which will force the token to not match the colon.

Comment: You mean, there's no way I can use ":" as delimiter?

Comment: So not possible to extract the string and an integeer from "command:3"?

Comment: yes, it is:  `sscanf(Command, "%7s:%d", Keyword, &Context);` on the other end, this accepts only commands that are 7 characters long.

Comment: @John, it's working, and I wonder why :D Can you please explain? Thank you so much.

Comment: the contents of the [] indicate characters to match.  if the first character in the [] is ^ it tells the function to match everything *except* the characters in the []

Comment: @kfmfe04 It doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

If you aren't particular about using sscanf, you could always use strtok, since what you want is to tokenize your string.

```
    char Command[20] = "command:3";

    char* key;
    int val;

    key = strtok(Command, ":");
    val = atoi(strtok(NULL, ":"));

    printf("Keyword:%s\n",key);
    printf("Context:%d\n",val);
```

This is much more readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

use a `%[` convention here. see the manual page of scanf: http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = "command:3";
    char s1[0xff];
    int d;
    sscanf(s, "%[^:]:%d", s1, &d);
    printf("here: %s:%d\n", s1, d);
    return 0;
}
```

which gives "here:command:3" as its output.